# Inline onchange event in Telerik MVC Integer TextBox with Razor engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik-mvc

I want to write an inline code block to handle onChange event for Integer textbox.
I found this :

```
&lt;% Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBox()
      .Name("IntegerTextBox")
      .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange(() =>
      {
         %&gt;
          function(e) {
          //event handling code
          }
         &lt;%
      })).Render();
 %&gt;
```

But it is for ASPX engine.
What is equivalent for this in razor engine?
I have tried following codes but i get error :

```
@{  
   Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBox()
   .Name("IntegerTextBox")
   .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange(() =>
    {
      @<text>
      function(e) {
         //event handling code
      }
      </text>
    })).Render();                                
}
```

And this :

```
@{  
   Html.Telerik().IntegerTextBox()
   .Name("IntegerTextBox")
   .ClientEvents(events => events.OnChange( 
                 @<text>
                  function(e){
                         //event handling code
                  }
                 </text>
    )).Render();   
 }
```

Errors are :

> Delegate 'System.Func' does not take 2 arguments.
>
> Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type.

Note : I am using 'RazorGenerator' as custom tool for views.When i remove that, i have no error but my view does not render.Should i use another html element such as number input?

Comment: your onchange lambda expression doesn't return string which may due to <text> tag try using Html.Raw

Comment: hi vishal sharma.did you mean i use Html.Raw instead of <text> tag? or i insert Html.Raw befor Html.telerik...? i did both.but yet not works.

Comment: you have to use something which turns your expression into string...here it is not..try html.raw().tohtmlstring() or tostring()